# How to handle the HttpClient Request using C#

Tags: c#

Created the API using entity framework model to get the request data from other system and want to update those information into database.

```
//API
[AllowAnonymous]
public string UploadUser()
{
    return "Welcome To SMART Web API";
}
```

and its accessible using: http://localhost:5958/api/UploadUser

Created the View Model to store the request data:

```
public class UserRequestViewModel
{
    public UserRequestViewModel()
    {
        REQDTL = new List<Line>();
    }
    public List<Line> REQDTL { get; set; }
    public int? REQLEN { get; set; }

    public class Line
    {
        [Description("Id")]
        public int? ID { get; set; }
        public int? Id
        {
            get
            {
                return this.ID;
            }
        }

        [Description("UserName")]
        public int? USERNAME { get; set; }
        public int? UserName
        {
            get
            {
                return this.USERNAME;
            }
        }

        [Description("Password")]
        public string PASSWORD { get; set; }
        public string Password
        {
            get
            {
                return this.PASSWORD;
            }
        }


    }

    public class Summary
    {
        public int? Id { get; set; }
        public int? UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }          

    }
    public List<Summary> GetSummary()
    {
        List<Summary> ret = this.REQDTL
            .Where(x => x.Id != null ) //Filter to applicable records           
            .Select(x => new Summary()
            {
                Id = x.Id,
                UserName = x.UserName,
                Password = x.Password,                   
            }
        ).ToList();

        return ret;
    }

}
```

}

My question is how to handle the below request data using my controller (Do I need to use PostAsync / GetAsync/ any other)

```
    {"REQLEN":4,"REQDTL":[{"ID":"48490","USERNAME":"Test1","PASSWORD":"Test1"},{"ID":"48491","UserName":"Test2","Password":"Test2"}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, to accept a post and use the data to talk to a SQL database, if you are using Web API, then you first create a model for the data format that you expect:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

}
```

Then you create an action in your controller like this:

```
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]MyModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        string myConnectionString = "...";
        string mySqlCommand = "UPDATE MyTable SET...";

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(mySqlCommand, conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }

        return Ok();
    }
    else
        return BadRequest("Invalid data");
}
```

(Of course, the sample data you posted looks more like a login attempt than something you would want to stick into a database, so I am guessing that you aren't really asking the right question.  If you are just learning, I would recommend finding a tutorial that is similar to what you are trying to do.  The ASP.Net templates have user authentication built in - it would be much more secure to use what they offer than to try to create your own if you are brand new to this type of work.  If you just start from a blank ASP.Net project and click "Run", there will already be a way to login, sign up, etc if you do it right.)